# Node JS - MongoDB x MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

Por que todo tutorial de Node JS que vemos, sempre é mostrado exemplo em MongoDB.

O que os dois tem que são tão utilizados?

Por que não utilizar o MySQL com Node?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um motivo do porquê de ser muito comum o uso de *Node.js* com *MongoDB* é porquê ambos lidam com a mesma estrutura de dados nativamente.

Node.js é um ambiente de execução javascript do lado do servidor. Javascript trabalha muito bem com [JSON](http://www.json.org/) (JavaScript Object Notation) e [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/introduction/) é orientado a documentos, que são similares a objetos JSON.

> Um registro no MongoDB é um documento, que é uma estrutura de dados
>   composta de pares de campo e valor. Os documentos MongoDB são
>   semelhantes aos objetos JSON. Os valores dos campos podem incluir
>   outros documentos, arrays e arrays de documentos.

Ou seja, ambos falam a mesma língua. Outro fator é que *Node.js* é muito escalável e por ser assíncrono está sendo muito usado em aplicações de tempo real que combina com o fato de *MongoDB* ser um NoSQL, onde é pressuposto maior escalabilidade com relação aos bancos de dados relacionais.

Tanto é incentivado que existe o [MEAN](http://mean.io/) (MongoDB, Express, Angular, Node.js), que fornece estrutura para se trabalhar com essas tecnologias.

E sim, é possível e também comumente usado *Node.js* com *MySQL*, tanto que existe o ORM [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/).

Quanto a utilizar um ou outro depende da necessidade e dos requisitos do negócio.

Answer (score 0):

Os banco de dados não relacionais (NoSQL) são excelentes para os novos projetos atuais, visto que um dos principais problemas atualmente esteja relacionado com processamento e entrega rápida ao usuário. E os banco de dados NoSQL permitem isso.

Falando especificamente de Mongo + Node (Javascript), ambos parece que foi feito um para o outro. Além disso, realizar pesquisas ou inserções é algo muito simples. Tem horas que até esqueço que estou trabalhando com banco de dados.

Também uso ElasticSearch, que também tem estrutura do tipo JSON, porém é levemente mais complexo a comunicação entre o Node + ElasticSearch.

Também uso Node + MySQL, mas foi somente um script pra fazer uns testes de velocidade, e posteriormente passar os dados para o ElasticSearch. Para meu projeto, o mesmo script em MySQL demorou 16 segundos e no ElasticSearch 0.01 segundos, 160x mais rápido que o MySQL!

Seja MongoDB, ElasticSearch, ou outros NoSQL, aconselho fortemente a estudar sobre eles.