# NoSQL e MYSQL - quando usar?

Tags: mysql, nosql

A pergunta pode ser um pouco genérica mas não sei como ser mais específico. Quando utilizar um banco nosql e quando utilizar um sql?

90% dos bancos ou mais possuem relacionamento.
`clientes se relacionam com vendas, vendas com produtos, produtos com estoques, estoques com empresas`. Portanto, há tabelas para criar os principais, no exemplo citado: `clientes`,`empresas`,`produtos`, e tabelas auxiliares que farão comunicação entre as demais tabelas, no caso, `vendas` que terá o `id_cliente`,`id_empresa`,`id_venda`,`total`,`desconto` e outra tabela pegando com o `id_venda` e o `id_produto`. Pois bem, este seria mais ou menos um mundo relacional. Mas como eu aplicaria isso num mundo nosql ou por quê aplicaria isso?

Ficaria redundante e fora da aplicabilidade de um nosql se eu fizesse:

```
{
   empresas: [
      {empresa1: {
            razao_social: "",
            produtos: [{produto1: {nome: "",}}, {produto2: {nome: "",}}]
      }
   ],
   clientes: ["mesmo modelo de empresas"],
   vendas: [
      {venda1: {cliente_id: 111, empresa_id: 222, produto_id: 333}}
   ]
}
```

Então, a pergunta é: em qual momento devo utilizar um nosql sendo que praticamente, todo o banco possui relacionamento entre as tabelas?

Comment: Felipe, essa já responde? Se não, então seja mais específico.

Comment: Também tem essas: [Em que tipo de aplicação posso usar MongoDB?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274320) ... [Node JS - MongoDB x MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166150/)

Comment: Relacionado tem: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14533/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96409/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203857/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/295902/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216855/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205171/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138621/101. Alguma ou o conjunto pode já ter respondido.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal, os links que me passaram serviram de grande ajuda.